# How to highlight rows based on a column value that only appears x amount of times?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, background-color

Using an example dataframe, df, as below:

| Name | Day |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | Monday |
| John | Thursday |
| Sam | Friday |
| Bob | Monday |
| Katie | Sunday |
| Kyle | Tuesday |
| Katie | Saturday |
| Bob | Wednesday |
| Katie | Sunday |
| Sam | Thursday |
| Joe | Friday |

What I want to do is to highlight a row say yellow if the value in the Name column only appears once and then say red if the value appears twice.

What I tried to do was group them by name and then do something like the following to highlight the rows with names that appeared once:

```
highlight = lambda x: ['background: yellow' if (x['Name'] != (x-1)['Name'] and x['Name'] != (x+1)['Name']) else '' for i in x]

df.style.apply(highlight, axis = 1)
```

However, this didn't work so I didn't get onto trying to highlight the rows with values in the name column that appeared twice. Despite trying to research it I don't fully understand how lambda x works so I don't know if you can apply an operator to access a previous row.

Edit:

In line with the recommended question I've tried the following:

```
def color_recommend():
    for index, row in enumerate(df):
        if df.Name.str.count(df.loc[i, 'Name']).sum() == 1:
            color = 'red'
        elif df.Name.str.count(df.loc[i, 'Name']).sum() == 2:
            color = 'green'
        else:
            color = 'white'
        return 'background-color: %s' % color
    
df.style.applymap(color_recommend)
```

But its still not working for me. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Style conditional formatting (highlight) on text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68056855/pandas-style-conditional-formatting-highlight-on-text)

Comment: Potentially but what I'm still stuck with is how to link the value of a cell to that in another cell. Say for example I group the rows by the Name column and I wanted to say if above or below is equal to the 'current' cell. How would I do that and then how would I take into account the first index and the last index given they wouldn't have a value above and below them respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a dictionary containing the mapping of `counts->color`, then use `value_counts` to calculate the frequency of each string appearing in the `Name` column, then `map` the calculated frequency with the `cmap` dictionary to create `colors`, finally apply `colors` on each column to get the result

```
cmap = {1: 'green', 2: 'yellow', 3: 'red'}
freq = df['Name'].map(df['Name'].value_counts())
colors = freq.map(cmap).radd('background-color: ')

df.style.apply(lambda s: colors)
```

Result

[image]