# How to highlight rows based on a column value that matches a string in Jinja?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am working with FLASK and Jinja. I have a dataframe named as df:

```
Name      Marks   Remarks
Joseph      40    Warning
Tom         60    Satisfied
```

In flask pass the dataframe as follows:

```
df=[df.to_html(classes='data', justify='center', header="true",index=False)]
```

In Jinja, I have the following code:

```
{% for grouped_table in df %}
     {{ grouped_table|safe }}
```

I would like to highly the background based on the value of "Remarks" column. When the value is "Warning" it should be red, otherwise green.

In the following article, [How to highlight rows based on a column value that only appears x amount of times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71677262/how-to-highlight-rows-based-on-a-column-value-that-only-appears-x-amount-of-time), it is mentioned that we can use `df.style.apply(lambda s: colors)` for highlighting a cell based on value.

However, I am not sure how to implement it in Jinja. Is it possible to implement the logic in FLASK and then pass it to Jinja?

Thanks in advance for any valuable suggestions/solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `to_html` it is possible to use the [styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/style.html) to set the properties of the table.
To set values depending on the background color you can use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap.html). This allows the properties to be assigned directly to the respective cells. All other properties can be assigned by normal css rules.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template 
)
import pandas as pd 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        [['Joseph', 40, 'Warning'], ['Tom', 60, 'Satisfied']],
        columns=['Name', 'Marks', 'Remarks']
    )

    def bg_color_by_value(value):
        clr = 'red' if value == 'Warning' else 'green'
        return f'background-color: {clr}'

    table = df.style\
            .applymap(bg_color_by_value, subset=['Remarks'])\
            .hide(axis='index')\
            .set_table_attributes('class="dataframe data"')\
            .to_html()

    return render_template('index.html', **locals())
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        table.dataframe {
            table-layout: fixed;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            color: #3f3f3f;
            font-family: Arial;
            width: 100%;
        }
        table.dataframe thead tr th {
            background-color: #777;
            color: #fff;
        }
        table.dataframe td, th 
        {
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #777;
        }
        table.dataframe tbody tr:nth-child(even)
        {
            background-color: #eee;
        }
        table.dataframe tbody tr td, 
        table.dataframe tbody tr th 
        {
            border: 1px dotted #ccc;
        }
        table.dataframe tbody tr:last-child td, 
        table.dataframe tbody tr:last-child th 
        {
            border-bottom: 0;
        }
        table.dataframe tbody tr:first-child td, 
        table.dataframe tbody tr:first-child th 
        {
            border-top: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    {{ table|safe }}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Detlef! I shall try your code and get back if i have any issues.

Comment: I have other tables displayed on the same HTML page. Is it possible to personalize the table styling for one table without affecting another table on the same HTML page?

Comment: Since you can assign each table its own class name or identifier with `set_table_attributes`, this is possible. The assignments by `applymap` only apply to one table. You can style each table individually.